# Optimize string builder in typescript

Tags: typescript, optimization

I wrote this function

```
function buildPredicate(skus: string[]): string | null {
    if (!skus) {
        return null;
    }

    let where = `masterData(current(masterVariant(sku=\"${skus[0]}\")))`;
    for (let i = 1; i < skus.length; i++) {
        where = where + ` OR masterData(current(masterVariant(sku=\"${skus[i]}\")))`;
    }
    return where;
}
```

and I would your help to optimize it. As you can see there is a common part of the string. Is it possible to use a map, or something similar?

Comment: 1. `map` over `skus` to add `masterData(current(masterVariant(sku=...)` 2. `join` it

Comment: PS: are you sure `skus` type is `[string]`, not `string[]`?

Comment: @zerkms you're right, omg it's friday.. my brain is f***d up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply `map` to produce the string and `join` to join it

```js
var skus = ['sku1','sku2','sku3'];
let where =  skus.map(sku =>  `masterData(current(masterVariant(sku=\"${sku}\")))`)
                 .join(' OR ');
console.log(where);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Array methods:

```
const clauses = skus.map(sku => `masterData(current(masterVariant(sku=\"${sku}\")))`)
return clauses.join(' OR ');
```

That said, this looks like some sort of SQL injection to me, and you should probably use prepared statements to avoid that (what if one of the strings contains a double quote, for example?).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yes I'm already catching that kind of error :)